# Angular JS: $index like parameter of a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want to pass the variable $index like parameter of a filter. The code is the next:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main" >
    <div ng-repeat="i in (filtered = (elements | myFilter: $index))" >

        <ul>
            <il ng-repeat="i in filtered">{{i.T}}</il>
        </ul>


    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input, index){
        var newArray = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x+=2){
             newArray.push(input[index]);   
        }
        return newArray;
    }
});


function Main($scope){
    $scope.elements = [
        { T: 't1', V: "v1"},
        { T: 't2', V: "v2"},
        { T: 't3', V: "v3"},
        { T: 't4', V: "v4"},
        { T: 't5', V: "v5"}
    ];
}
```

I have proved if i pass a number like parameter, it is working. But when i pass the variable $index the code isn`t working.

Is there anyway to pass the variable $index or the index of the ng-repeat like a parameter in a filter?

Greetings.

Edit:

Really, I want to show something like that:

...
t1t2
t3t4
t5
...
or in HTML:

...

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <il>t1</il>
       <il>t2</il>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
       <il>t3</il>
       <il>t4</il>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
       <il>t5</il>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What you try to do? increase `ng-repeat` step?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason to use `$index` in filter since filter runs over all list.

However I would implement the same logic without filter, like:

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="i in elements" >
        <ul>
            <il ng-show="$index % 2 == 0">{{i.T}}</il>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/716/)**</kbd>

With filter you can write something like:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="i in elements | myFilter" >
        <ul>
            <il>{{i.T}}</il>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
.filter("myFilter", function(){
    return function(input){
        console.log(input);

        var newArray = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x+=2){
             newArray.push(input[x]);   
        }
        return newArray;
    }
});
```

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/718/)**</kbd>